# Maybe you should Chew on This for a while!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, lateral-thinking

I looked into a big black bag and found some dip.

I chewed on it.

When I got to the end I spit out towards a light that never seems to move.

As I traveled towards this light, I noticed that the light seemed to move towards me as I moved toward it.

Eventually, the light appeared to be directly overhead!

> What am I wearing?

---

Hint:

> I am in the Northern Hemisphere and it is a cloudless night.

Comment: Nothing, because you’re tripping out on LSD  Looks like a fun one Chowzen, +1!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're wearing

> something very warm

because you end up at

> the North Pole.

*I looked into a big black bag and found some dip.*

> The big black bag is the night sky. The dip is the [Big Dipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Dipper).

*I chewed on it.*

*When I got to the end I spit out towards a light that never seems to move.*

> The end of the Big Dipper points towards [Polaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaris), the star which is always found to the north.

*As I traveled towards this light, I noticed that the light seemed to move towards me as I moved toward it.*

> **Explanation from OP:** If you stand still and watch the stars from dusk till dawn, Polaris is the one star that does not move, or rotate through the heavens. As you travel towards it, though, its apparent position in the sky changes from relatively low in the sky (far away) to a higher position (closer to you) as your latitude increases to 90°. Polaris is, on an extreme scale, slightly closer to you at the north pole than it is when you are at the equator.

*Eventually, the light appeared to be directly overhead!*

> Polaris would be directly overhead if you're near the North Pole, which must be what you've been travelling towards.

Comment: Yes, that's it! All of my green check marks are in the laundry, as soon as one is dry, I'll send it over.

Comment: This was my first thought on reading the riddle as well, but I'd be curious about an explanation for the clue "the light seemed to move towards me as I moved towards it" - this is not my experience with moving towards the answer!

Comment: @Chowzen see tmpearce's comment ^ ... this didn't make sense to me either

Comment: Rot13(Vs lbh fgnaq fgvyy naq jngpu gur fgnef sebz qhfx 'gvyy qnja,  Cbynevf vf gur bar fgne gung qbrf abg zbir, be ebgngr guebhtu gur urniraf. Nf lbh geniry gbjneq vg, gubhtu, vgf nccnerag cbfvgvba va gur fxl punatrf sebz eryngviryl ybj va gur fxl (sne njnl), gb n uvture cbfvgvba (pybfre gb lbh) nf lbhe yngvghqr vapernfrf gb 90°. Cbynevf vf, ba na rkgerzr fpnyr, fyvtugyl pybfre gb lbh ng gur abegu cbyr guna vg vf jura lbh ner ng gur rdhngbe.)

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of angle as connected to distance. Thanks; edited into the post (cc @tmpearce).

Comment: Trigonometry rules!

Answer (score 6):

So because of the knowledge tag I don't think this is the correct answer but
it popped into my head and for some reason it kinda fits:

> 3D glasses

I looked into a big black bag and found some dip.

> Love me some nacho's at the cinema (with dip of course)

I chewed on it.

> Yup love to do that

When I got to the end I spit out towards a light that never seems to move.

> When the movie finally starts I'm already at the end of my nacho's, and the light that never seems to move would be the screen on which they project.

As I traveled towards this light, I noticed that the light seemed to move towards me as I moved toward it.

> With 3D glasses the figures seem to move towards you but if you take off the glasses the light is again fixed on the screen.

Eventually, the light appeared to be directly overhead!

> The projection light travels over your head to towards the screen.

What am I wearing?

> So what you are wearing are 3D glasses to see the figures move towards you from a stationary projection on the wall that travels over your head while eating nacho's with dip. and yes my brain just went that way for some reason :p

Comment: +1, just cause it's interesting. :) You're right, though, you'll need [tag:knowledge] of a specific kind for the correct answer. Hint is forthcoming...